# How to convert Date format in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, datepicker

I am getting date from system config using `datepicker` date format is `dd/mm/yy`

I want to convert it in to `yy/mm/dd H:i:s` and able to convert date in format: `yy/mm/dd` but time is not coming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This way i convert date format

```
protected $timezone;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
......
)
{
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
}

$dateTimeZone = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($yourdate))->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Comment: $dateTimeZone = (new \DateTime($yourdate))->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'); will probably work too (without the timezone injection).

Comment: You asked the question, and you answered it. Then you put a comment for yourself to accept the answer?

Comment: It's not working when your timezone is different, this solution works well: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/372331/82670

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, you can convert date to any format by using a combination of date and strtotime function.

Please try below format to convert date:

> date(format, strtotime(originaldate))

Suppose, you have original date as `mm/dd/yy` (say 21/03/10) and you want to convert it to yy/mm/dd H:i:s format (say 10/03/21 00:00:00), then try below code:

> $originalDate = "21/03/10";
>
> $newDate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora  your solution is not work...!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date
  ){
        $this->date =  $date;
  }

  public function getTimeconverter($yourdate)
    {
        return $this->date->date($yourdate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> **Please try the code**

```
protected $date;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date
) {
        $this->date =  $date;
}

public function getFormatedDate($yourdate)
{
    $yourdate = "2022-10-09 06:00:00";
    return $this->date->date(strtotime($yourdate))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```